# GDK Send Email with attachment

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I am trying to send an email with an attachment, but it seems to be erroring out:

```
 private void sendEmail(File pictureFile){
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(pictureFile);
    Date dt = new Date();

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("text/plain");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"a@gmail.com", "b@gmail.com"});
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Google Glass Capture");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "Taken "+ dt.toString());
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    try {
            Log.d("Msg","Trying to send mail");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,"pick"));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Log.e("ERR","Error " + ex.toString());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                           "There are no email clients installed.", 
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Is there a different way to send mail with google glass then that of android?

Comment: Erroring out ? Can you tell us what the error message is or better why dont you show us the logs ?

Comment: The error is basically a resource not being disposed.  This code brings up a no default email client dialog in glass.

Comment: I think this is more of a feature that will be available once the GDK gets an Update